# New table from other table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I Have a dataframe like this

[image]

I would like to create a new table transforming the months columns (April and may) in just one column like this.

[image]

But I can't to use just unpivot columns in same table, because the sum of the payment column by column A must stay as it is in first dateframe, (If I create a sum metric in the dashboard, it returns  1299 for A30FF, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Click select the first two columns, right click, unpivot other columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column A", "payment"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

[image]

or potentially this, which spread the payment across all rows

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column A", "payment"}, "Month", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Column A"}, {
    {"data", each 
    let a= Table.RowCount(_),
     b=Table.AddColumn(_,"new payment", each [payment]/a,type number) 
    in b  }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"new payment","Attribute", "Value"}, {"Payment","Month", "Value" })
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]